# PySpark join on ID then on year and month from 'date' column

Tags: apache-spark, date, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 PySpark dataframes and want to join on "ID", then on a *year* from "date1" and "date2" columns and then on *month* of the same date columns.

df1:

```
ID   col1     date1
1    1     2018-01-05
1    2     2018-02-05
2    4     2018-04-05
2    1     2018-05-05
3    1     2019-01-05
3    4     2019-02-05
```

df2:

```
ID   col2     date2
1    1     2018-01-08
1    1     2018-02-08
2    4     2018-04-08
2    3     2018-05-08
3    1     2019-01-08
3    4     2019-02-08
```

Expected output:

```
ID   col1     date1     col2     date2
1    1     2018-01-05    1     2018-01-08
1    2     2018-02-05    1     2018-02-08
2    4     2018-04-05    4     2018-04-08
2    1     2018-05-05    3     2018-05-08
3    1     2019-01-05    1     2019-01-08
3    4     2019-02-05    4     2019-02-08
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```py
df = df1.join(df2, (ID & (df1.F.year(date1) == df2.F.year(date2)) & (df1.F.month(date1) == df2.F.month(date2))
```

How to join on date's month and year?

Comment: the `year` function extracts the year from the date/ts column of a dataframe -- it is not part of the dataframe already. so, the correct syntax would be `F.year(df1.date1)`. same goes for `month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to it like this:

```py
join_on = (df1.ID == df2.ID) & \
          (F.year(df1.date1) == F.year(df2.date2)) & \
          (F.month(df1.date1) == F.month(df2.date2))
df = df1.join(df2, join_on)
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, '2018-01-05'),
     (1, 2, '2018-02-05'),
     (2, 4, '2018-04-05'),
     (2, 1, '2018-05-05'),
     (3, 1, '2019-01-05'),
     (3, 4, '2019-02-05')],
    ['ID', 'col1', 'date1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1, '2018-01-08'),
     (1, 1, '2018-02-08'),
     (2, 4, '2018-04-08'),
     (2, 3, '2018-05-08'),
     (3, 1, '2019-01-08'),
     (3, 4, '2019-02-08')],
    ['ID', 'col2', 'date2'])

join_on = (df1.ID == df2.ID) & \
          (F.year(df1.date1) == F.year(df2.date2)) & \
          (F.month(df1.date1) == F.month(df2.date2))
df = df1.join(df2, join_on).drop(df2.ID)

df.show()
# +---+----+----------+----+----------+
# | ID|col1|     date1|col2|     date2|
# +---+----+----------+----+----------+
# |  1|   1|2018-01-05|   1|2018-01-08|
# |  1|   2|2018-02-05|   1|2018-02-08|
# |  2|   4|2018-04-05|   4|2018-04-08|
# |  2|   1|2018-05-05|   3|2018-05-08|
# |  3|   1|2019-01-05|   1|2019-01-08|
# |  3|   4|2019-02-05|   4|2019-02-08|
# +---+----+----------+----+----------+
```